# Spelling a word with a double letter in spoken French

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

I vaguely recall that when spelling a word with a double letter like "A**nn**e" or "vi**ll**e" in spoken French (say, spelling your name to someone over the phone), one would not say

> "V, I, L, L, E"

but rather say

> "V, I, deux L, E"

or

> "V, I, double L, E"

but I don't remember whether it is "deux" or "double." I tried searching on Google and on this site, but I can't seem to find this discussed anywhere.

Comment: La lettre *Double L* n'est pas une lettre de l'alphabet français, elle ne fait pas non plus partie des ligatures (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ligature). Votre troisième proposition n'est donc pas immédiatement audible par un francophone, la deuxième est la plus courante et la première parfois utilisée pour épeler des noms compliqués ou étrangers

Comment: @Personne: Je ne comprends pas votre argument. "Double 0" n'est pas un chiffre mais tout le monde en France comprends "double 0, 7". Je ne pense pas qu'un francophone ait de difficulté a comprendre la troisième proposition, meme si elle n'est pas naturelle. A titre d'anecdote, le rappeur PASSI épèle souvent son nom de cette manière: "P,A,double S,I".

Comment: @Taladris — "Double 0" est du domaine mathématique, et, *double* est pluri-polysémique (néologisme tautologique humoristique :-) ; un *francophone* est imprécis, donc, *un francophone ‘hexagonal’* même s'il a entendu « James Bond zéro zéro sept » à la sortie des premiers films, est capable de décoder "double 0, 7", mais ce sera pour lui anglicisme qui semble entré dans le langage des nouvelles générations  attentives à la musique anglo-saxonne.

Comment: @Taladris … alors que "Double V" est une lettre, et que  "Double 0" peut être une touche de calculatrice.

Comment: @Personne - Vous ne pensez pas que votre première remarque serait mieux placé comme réponse?

Comment: @HarryAudus — https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personnellement, j'ai toujours dit et entendu dans mon entourage (je suis Parisien) :

> V, I, deux L, E

Comment: oui, on serait bien embêtés sinon avec « double v ».

Comment: Y a-t-il liaison entre deux et L ?

Comment: @AmandeAdorable: Oui, sans hésitation. `deux z'ailes` ;-)

Comment: @AmandeAdorable J'en déduis qu'on dit "double L" au Québec, c'est ça ?

Comment: @jlliagre Non non, c'est _deux_ pour moi, mais la liaison je me demandais, peut-être parce que dans un code postal canadien il n'y en a pas (H2L...), j'ai une hésitation.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Ah, ok. Suivant les locuteurs, la liaison se fait parfois ici dans des contextes similaires (Terminal 2A à Roissy-CdG ou département 2A - Corse-du-Sud).

Answer (score 5):

As a French person, it is "deux". I never heard "double" and would find it a bit odd.

Although you can still spell the letter twice. (But be aware of the possible confusion. Some people might not be sure if you just repeated the letter for clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers mention, this is "deux" and not "double".

A few words about the usage: for someone who started school in the late 70's, we have been taught to spell `V I deux L E` (western suburbs of Paris).

Nowadays, I hear more and more the spelling `V I L L E`. My wild guess is that this is because we are more often spelling in foreign languages (or native words to foreign languages), where everyone will spell letter by letter (it would not make sense to spell VILLE in English using the word "deux")